# How to modify the (meta_value) in the (wp_usermeta table) with Wordpress function?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, wordpress

I want to modify the value in a specific table in mysql using the **$wpdb** function.

[image: Example image]

How can I change the meta_value value1 to value2, which corresponds to the currently logged in user_id in the wp_usermeta table.

Comment: You should first read the documentation and look for some relevant [articles](https://designmodo.com/wpdb-object-wordpress/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**update_user_meta**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_user_meta)

Update user meta field based on user ID.

```
function my_custom_function(){
    $user_id = get_current_user_id(); // Get logged in userid
    update_user_meta($user_id, 'first_name', 'value2');
}
add_action('init','my_custom_function');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that via the following code.

```
gloal $wpdb;
$wpdb->query("UPDATE wp_usermeta SET meta_value = 'value2' WHERE meta_key = 'first_name' and user_id = '1'");
```